# Factoryboy Django model with default fuzzyfields

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I am using factoryboy to mock up a model like the one below, and I wonder if there is a cleaner way that doesn't involve replicating all the fields.

```
class ShippingContainer(models.Model):
    weight = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    objects = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    serial_number = models.IntegerField(null=False)


class ShippingContainerFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = ShippingContainer

    weight = FuzzyInteger(0, 500)
    objects = FuzzyInteger(0, 500)
    serial_number = FuzzyInteger(0, 500)
```

It would be nice if factoryboy just deduced the numeric nature of the model fields and didn't need the factory fields, such as

```
class ShippingContainerFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = ShippingContainer
```

is this possible?

Comment: But how FactoryBoy would know that the integer need to be between 0 and 500?

Comment: I would be okay with defaults that are the range of the integerfield, or in a super-clever world Factoryboy could introspect on the options declared in the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you can do that in `factory`. But you can do it in a single line with `model_mommy`

Install model_mommy.

```
$ pip install model_mommy
```

Create a dummy model.

```
from model_mommy import mommy
from your_app.models import ShippingContainer

dummy_shipping_container = mommy.make('ShippingContainer')
```